# Может ли Docx библеотека для c# создавать формулы?

Tags: c#, lib, docx

Роюсь , роюсь у https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX и http://cathalscorner.blogspot.com/2010/ , но ни как не могу найти хоть какие то упоминания формул... Дорогие стеки и оферфолы, подскажите) Если либа не может, подскажите другую удобную библиотеку с такой фичей?

Comment: Исправьте пожалуйста орфографические ошибки и постарайтесь задавать вопрос по существу. Это не придирка, а дружеский совет. По Вашему вопросу посмотрите на https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалась, что формулы создавать не может, но может вставлять кусочки документов с формулами, без вреда для них самих...  Костыльно но робит)